# JAVA pdfbox & GROOVY - show Bookmark when PDF is opened, setPageMode not working

Tags: java, groovy, pdfbox, bookmarks

I am trying to merge all the PDF files and create bookmark, it is working well.
The last step was to set a feature for automatically showing bookmark when PDF is opened.

I have tested the following codes in pdfbox-2.0.20.

Part of code below ...

```
totalPages = totalPages + pdfDocPages
            println it["TLF_NUM"] + ": " + it["TLF_TITLE"]
            def page = pages.get( totalPages - pdfDocPages);
            def dest = new PDPageFitWidthDestination()
            dest.setPage(page)

            def bookmark = new PDOutlineItem()
            bookmark.setDestination(dest)
            bookmark.setTitle( it["TLF_NUM"] + ": " + it["TLF_TITLE"] )
            pagesOutline.appendChild( bookmark )
                        }
                    }
            }

    pagesOutline.openNode()

    outline.openNode()

    pdfDocument.getDocumentCatalog().setPageMode(PageMode.USE_OUTLINES)

    pdfDocument.save(pdfoutfullpath)
    pdfDocument.close()
    }
```

The error I got was listed below.

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No 
signature of method: org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocumentCatalog.setPageMode() is applicable for 
argument types: (org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PageMode) values: [USE_OUTLINES]
Possible solutions: 
setPageMode(java.lang.String), getPageMode()
     at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:95)
     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1058)
     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:886)
     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:706)
     at MergePDFBookmarks.invokeMethod(Script1.groovy)
     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper$2.run(InvokerHelper.java:415)
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: 
org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocumentCatalog.setPageMode() is applicable for argument types: 
(org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PageMode) values: [USE_OUTLINES]
Possible solutions: 
setPageMode(java.lang.String), getPageMode()
```

Comment: I suspect you have a pdfbox 1.8 .jar file in your classpath. Because the String argument is in 1.8 not in 2.0. Clean up old stuff both in development and runtime.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr, thank you! Yeah, you're right. But I have to use 1.8 since there were some modules only applicable to 1.8, not 2.0. So by using 1.8, how should I modify the code above to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Per the comments, it turns out you are using 1.8 and not 2.0. Delete the .jar files from the versions you aren't using. You can't use both.

In 1.8, use

```
pdfDocument.getDocumentCatalog().setPageMode(PDDocumentCatalog.PAGE_MODE_USE_OUTLINES)
```

or

```
pdfDocument.getDocumentCatalog().setPageMode("UseOutlines")
```

Comment: Thank you for providing the solutions, for 1st method, it is showing error 'org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script1.groovy: 81: Apparent variable 'PDDocumentCatalog' was found in a static scope but doesn't refer to a local variable, static field or class.' For 2nd method, it didn't has any error message but not automatically showing bookmark when open the PDF.

Comment: Did you delete the 2.0 jars from develop and runtime environments? And is there really only one version left? Re the first code - I don't know if it is the correct syntax. Maybe the whole path of PDDocumentCatalog is needed, i.e. org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocumentCatalog ? Re 2nd code, please share the result PDF.